# Need help with unit circle trig coordinates.

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

I'm in over my head and need some help with this question.

[image]

Sorry if this is too simple for you but I'm really struggling. I can't for the life of me figure out how to write the angles A in terms of B or how to get formula for tan b in terms Tan ${B\over 2}$ using these coordinates. Any help of direction would be greatly appreciated.

- Q1 Express Angle A in terms of angle B, stating all theorems used.
- Q2 deduce a formula for tan B in terms of tan ${B\over 2}$ using parameterisation a in pic.

I have it that $A= {B\over 2}$ is it that simple @almagest?

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMsGb.jpg): [image]

Comment: Can you see another angle in the diagram which equals angle $A$?

Comment: ORQ is equal I see that and i tried using compound angles but it all went wrong.

Comment: Correct! So what is the relationship between angles $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: For the first question, use the strong version of the [Exterior Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_angle_theorem).

Comment: Apologies @N.F.Taussig, I have amended the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: try drawing a few more lines.
[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm over thinking it too much but A=0.5(pi/2 - B)

Comment: The theorem you need for B is that angle POR = angle ORQ + angle OQR. Why? Because the angles in a triangle add up to 180 deg and so do the two angles making up a straight line (ie angle POR +angle ROQ = 180 deg).